# How do add basic form validation to Shopify Liquid?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, shopify, liquid

I need to add some form validation to the account/register Shopify path on my store. As of now a new user can be created using any characters, I can have my first name be "!@#$!@" and it will accept it as a new user. I simply want a condition that checks to make sure the first and last names only include letters and not numbers or symbols.

I am new to Liquid and I am not sure how to add basic JavaScript or Liquid conditions to forms yet. I am using the Dawn theme and the repo file path in question is templates/customers/register.liquid.

I tried adding a JavaSchipt function to the file with a console.log and a getById. I was expecting to see console.logs in the dev tools and my preventDefault() to work, but they have not worked for me yet.

EDIT:

Task complete with HTML and REGEX =
I believe the HTML attribute is "pattern" and it allows you to add powerful REGEX for form validation.

Comment: Keep trying then. You need to use JS. Before you submit the form, you check the fields to ensure you approve of them. Once you do, you can then submit. There has to be 100,000 of these answers (form validation) on SO here, I am sure you can find one to match your needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to get into JavaScript. Just add required in form with validation through regular expression in HTML tag. Required isn't necessary for your question. But you should include it. Because by default, Shopify don't use that.

Comment: I might recommend showing how how to achieve this. In Stack Overflow you can even show a running code samples to help others see the answer live. It definitely goes a long way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).